# ParseCrashReport sending reports issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, crash-reports

I'm trying to integrate parseCrashReport into my ios app, here's my code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //Setting status Bar to White color
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    [ParseCrashReporting enable];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"......"
                  clientKey:@"......"];

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"Everything is ok. This is just a test crash."];
    });

}
```

When I restart my app after the crash nothing is sent to the server and I' can't find the crash reports in parse server. I'm using `Parse 1.7.2`

Comment: may be [this link](http://blog.parse.com/learn/introducing-parse-crash-reporting-2/) support you

Comment: Thank you for the link, I came back to this page

Comment: @EdwardAnthony This was version issue try to update parse SDK

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, and I'm using current Parse everything.  I'm new to the whole thing, but their documentation on this topic is not of the otherwise excellent caliber that Parse provides.  Circular references, and also it just says "do this", where "this" is actually confusing (parse new).  I created a folder that contains nothing, but is used by the run script.  What?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was related to parse version and it was fixed in later version